# Store MongoClient.connect()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I work on a project whose code is divided into multiple js files. Until now, I 've been calling `MongoClient.connect()` multiple times (in each file using the db). That's when I got multiple deprecation warnings:

```
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
the options [dbName] is not supported
the options [srvHost] is not supported
the options [credentials] is not supported
```

I quickly found out it was related to all these open connections. Even though I can store MongoClient in a separate file, ***how can I store `MongoClient.connect()`***, since a code that uses the database looks like that:

```js
MongoClient.connect((err) => {
    // code here
});
```

and not like that:

```js
MongoClient.connect()
// code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** well, it seemed to work, but it looks like the exports of the file are equal to `{}`...

---

The problem seems to be solved by putting the connection in a separate file (yes, I finally found out how to do it!).

#### mongoClient.js

```js
require("dotenv").config();

// Declaring and configuring the mongoDB client
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const mongo = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_AUTH, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

mongo.connect((err, result) => { // note the 'result':

    // result == mongo ✅

    // Exports the connection
    module.exports = result;

    // Logs out if the process is killed
    process.on("SIGINT", function () {
        mongo.close();
    });
});
```

#### Other file using the db

```js
const mongo = require("./mongoClient")

const collection = mongo.db("niceDB").collection("coolCollection")
collection.findOne({fancy: "document"}); // It works!
```